# Viewmodel values not being returned to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I found some similar posts to mine, but I couldn't find an answer that suits my needs for this. 
Problem is as follows:

I have a viewmodel like this:

```
public class PrefViewModel
{
    public SelectList countries { get; set; }
    public SelectList Provincies { get; set; }
    public ApplicationUser user { get; set; }
    public Preference MyPref{ get; set; }

    public int mycountry { get; set; }
    public int myprovince { get; set; }
 }
```

my cshtml looks like this:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Index","Preferences", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="control-label col-md-10">
                    <span class="textvak">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user.UserName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </span>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Email, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="control-label col-md-10">
                    <span class="textvak">
                       @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user.Email, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
                    </span>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Unhashed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.user.Unhashed, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "password" } })

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Unhashed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Provincie.Land, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="control-label col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.mycountry, Model.countries, new { Name = "ddlLand", id = "ddlLanden", @class = "textvak" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Provincie.Land, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.user.Provincie, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="control-label col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.myprovince, Model.Provincies, new { @class = "textvak" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.user.Provincie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

    <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value=@Resources.Wijzig class="btn btn-default" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        }
```

and in my controller I try to get the posted PrefViewModel back as follows:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(PrefViewModel TestMymodel)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            int myCountry = TestMymodel.mycountry;
            int myprovince = TestMymodel.myprovince;
        }

       return View();
    }
```

My problem is that the PrefViewModel TestMymodel never is filled with the values I thought i'm posting back. Even more strange to me is the fact that I do get the Unhashed password back, but all other values are 0 or null.
I can put values inside the PrefViewModel to load the page and that works, but on Posting it's almost entirely empty.

Any ideas?

**edit:** Would it make any difference that I did change the default model to one that I made up myself? Cause when I Call the Create action for example, I do get the values back in my post (from create offcourse). I'm getting a bit desperate

**edit2:** this is what was posted:

__RequestVerificationToken:-JYcw0CH2zZ7WrGUiYJM6-R6VxfL41ykTD5EHUjgtyyFcN01AaUU61BYuaRNr4oPdEvDq09aYsOFdb8fObJTXMnTKulADVkGY8CrBG3U71QXw0g7Th86WKl1up4059Zy7mW0SlrWGJpehed586v_5g2
user.Unhashed:Jonas1234-
user.Unhashed:Jonas1234-
ddlLand:1
ddlProvincie:3

(can't add picture with my reputation, so here a link to the full post: http://postimg.org/image/id95wjcxp/ )

Ok, when I change the name of the dropdownlists to the PrefViewModel property name those values get returned correct.

Comment: Are you getting the `mycountry` and `myprovince` values back?

Comment: no I don't. I only get the user.Unhashed in my TestMymodel

Comment: Could you show what gets POSTed? The actual payload sent from the client. You could use the Network tab of your web browser's developer toolbar to capture that.

Comment: I added what gets posted to the Original question under edit2

Comment: Weird, there are some `ddlLand` and `ddlLand` values being sent to the server which are nowhere present in your markup. Are you using some javascript to submit this form? Or maybe some js plugins which are *enhancing* those dropdowns and renaming them? This explains why only the you are getting only the `Unhashed` value back - it's the only thing submitted to the server.

Comment: No, I didn't use any javascript. But I did explicitly change the name of the dropdownlistsfor to ddlLand and ddlProvince. After changing those names to mycountry and myprovince I do get the values mycountry and myprovince back where I expect them. Now remains the question where my user info went

Comment: Your username textbox is `disabled`. This means that the value will never be sent to the server. That's why you are getting null on the server. Use `readonly` without `disabled`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you have overriden the names of the drop down lists to some values which are different than the property names in your view model. That's why the values are not successfully bound back. Make sure that your input fields respect the same names as the properties on your view model if you want the default model binder to be able to bind them back to the view model.

Also your username textbox has the disabled flag:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user.UserName, new { disabled = "disabled", @readonly = "readonly" })
```

so it will not be submitted back to the server. You might need to add an additional hidden field if you want those values to travel back. Or simply use `readonly` without `disabled` attribute. Both attributes prevent the user from modifying the value in the corresponding input field but in addition to that the `disabled` attribute strips it from the POST payload when the form is submitted.

So you may use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.user.UserName, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```